# Symfony2 multiple roles for marketplace structure (FOSUser/PUGXMultiUser)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'm working on a marketplace app with Symfony2.
I have two user roles : `buyer` and `seller`.

The "default" role is the `buyer` since everyone registered will be able to use the marketplace as buyer.
I'm currently using `FOSUserBundle` for the user management but I recently become stuck when I wanted to implement the `seller` part of the app.

I need to have three "registration" services, either :

- A user decides to register as `buyer`, this is the main registration form I have set up with FOSUserBundle
- A user decides to register as `seller`, then I need another registration form with more required fields, but anyway a user with the role `seller` will also have the role `buyer` which is the base role for all users.
- A user currently registered as `buyer` decides to upgrade his account to a `seller` one, only the additionnal fields will be asked

Since every registered user has the `buyer` role my classes are like :

```
class User extends BaseUser implements UserInterface, \Serializable // Buyer
{
   // ...

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Seller",inversedBy="user")
    * @ORR\JoinColumn(name="seller_id",referencedColumn="id")
    **/
    private $seller;
}

class Seller
{
    // ...

}
```

In order to be able to handle multiple registration form, I recently tried to use `PUGXMultiUserBundle`, but I don't know how to make it work with my code.

I am using a OneToOne relationship to link `buyer` and `seller` but PUGXMultiUserBundle requires to use inheritance with discriminator.
This is not a problem, I can change my code and already tried to do it but what stucks me is that the `User` class have to be abstract.

From what I understood, my classes have to be like :

```
User extends BaseUser (abstract)
Buyer extends User
Seller extends User
```

But I have :

```
User extends BaseUser (semantically my Buyer class)
Seller extends User
```

What should I do ? How can I reorganise my class hierarchy ? Is PUGXMultiUserBundle an appropriate solution for what I want ?

Thanks